# "Invalid Token" when trying to validate account in .NET Core 7 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have check a lot of resources about this problem but none applies to my case.

I am using this code to generate the token that is sent in the e-mail:

```
string token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var callbackUrl = $"{_request.Scheme}://{_request.Host}{_request.PathBase}/Authenticate/Security/ConfirmEmail/{user.Id}?token={WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token))}";
```

When e-mail is received and clicked the link, this code is run:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

if (user is null)
    return new Result { Success = false, Errors = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() { { "NotFound", new string[] { "Usuario no encontrado " } } } };

IdentityResult result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token)));
```

When debugging, I can check that the token generated by

```
string token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

is exactly the same after running

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token))
```

I am in the same development machine, so the `MachineKey` problem is not the cause. I am using user time stamp, but it is correctly set and never changed.

Since generation is made by `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` and validation is made by `ConfirmEmailAsync`, the purpose of the key is the same, and equal to `Confirmation`.

What else can I check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I am using a custom user store. When I loaded the ApplicationUser, I forgot to set the security stamp field.

Now, when loading the user, I am using this method to set the properties:

```
    private static ApplicationUser? GetUserData(Usuario? u)
    {
        if (u == null)
            return null;

        return new ApplicationUser
        {
            Id = u.UsuarioId,
            UserName = u.UsuarioLogin,
            FirstName = u.UsuarioNombre,
            LastName = u.UsuarioApellido,
            PhoneNumber = u.UsuarioTelefono,
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = u.UsuarioTelefonoConfirmado,
            Email = u.UsuarioEmail,
            EmailConfirmed = u.UsuarioEmailConfirmado,
            PasswordHash = u.UsuarioPasswordHash,
            SecurityStamp = u.UsuarioSecurityStamp
        };
    }
```

Of course, the method is called from `public async Task<ApplicationUser?> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` of custom user store.

Cheers
Jaime